# Why did they implemented a map not with a hashtable?

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

Why did they implemented a Map with a red-black tree which has complexity of O(log) and not with a hashtable which has a complexity of O(1) ?

Comment: They also have HashMap. Hash table is probabilistic and has only expected time performance in contrast to a red-black tree which has worst case running time guarantees

Comment: Only "they" can answer this kind of question...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which programming language or library is this in reference to? (I assume Java?) And can you elaborate on what you mean by "they implemented a Map?" Java has both a TreeMap and a HashMap.